# How to align text to bottom of div without a fixed height

Tags: html, css

I will extract the style later.  I want to learn how to do this with straight up HTML.

I want the *Select* and *Description* labels to be aligned with the bottom of the green div.  As you can see, **vertical-align: bottom;** is not working and **position: absolute; bottom: 0;** is putting the text at the bottom of the wrapper div.  [Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdlarue/67ybug7m/).  Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

[image]

[image]

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 80%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto; float: left">
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; margin: 0 0 0 0; float: left; background-color: aqua;">
    <div id="heading" class="row">
      <p style="text-align: center;">This is a title</p>
      <div style="width: 15%; float: left; background-color: yellow;">
        <label style="vertical-align: bottom; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">Select</label>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 70%; float: left; background-color: orange;">
        <label style="vertical-align: bottom; ">Description</label>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 15%; float: left; background-color:green;">
        <label style="vertical-align: bottom; ">Number of items available for a very long title</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase the floats, use `display: inline-block` instead, put the three elements in a wrapper, assign `vertical-align: bottom` to that and make sure not to leave spaces or linebreaks between those three elements (which otherwise results in unwanted whitespace, which again causes the elements not to fit within their container):

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 80%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto; float: left">
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; margin: 0 0 0 0; float: left; background-color: aqua;">
    <div id="heading" class="row">
      <p style="text-align: center;">This is a title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap1" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
      <div style="width: 15%; background-color: yellow; display: inline-block;">
        <label style="vertical-align: bottom; ">Select</label>
      </div><div style="width: 70%; background-color: orange; display: inline-block;">
        <label style="vertical-align: bottom; ">Description</label>
      </div><div style="width: 15%; background-color:green; display: inline-block;">
        <label style="vertical-align: bottom; ">Number of items available for a very long title</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2hxt8x1f/1/

P.S.: Oh, and you really should start NOT using inline styles but using external CSS and classes instead - it's much clearer to work with.

Comment: I agree with you completely, I will be using external CSS and classes but, for now, I'm really trying to learn how to position elements according to a predefined layout and I'm just learning about the layers of divs, columns, rows, containers, etc.  It's a lot!  :-~

Comment: I am using the exact same technique to vertical-align elements in the middle, but changing the size of the checkbox appears to break the pattern.  I have a new question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/43621013/1735836